# How to make AWS ELB and AspNetCore routing work together?

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I am hosting a set of Asp.Net Core 2.0 apps on AWS Fargate, behind a single ELB load balancer that has multiple roles to route to different microservices in order to hide that microservice complexity from the clients.

I have 3 rules set as follows:

```
/auth* -> AuthMicroservice
/reports* -> BI Microservice
default -> Web Client
```

The rules seem to work but I am getting `404`'s on both microservices. I suspect because ELB isn't dropping the `/auth` and `/reports` segments from the path, making Asp.Net routing fail because of the unknown prefixes.

I am considering two alternatives to solve this problem:

1. Have OWIN middleware (in production only) discard the first path segment on all requests to compensate for the ELB path matching
2. Have ELB drop whatever it matched from the path it send to the actual app

I'm leaning more towards the second option, only because it makes development and production environments more similar.

Does anybody know how to make ELB drop the matched path segments?

Does Asp.Net provide pre-made functionality to drop path segments without OWIN middleware?